# PHP - Printing one report per page

Tags: php, printing

I have a timeclock system where i need to print a report for each user... and dont have anyh clue how to do this... im trying to see if DOMPDF its a solution but the website is off.

My ideia is create a pdf with one report in each page... but dont have a clue without read the DOMPDF class..

Any other solution, maybe js, dunno.

Regards,
Roberto

Comment: And the problem is what exactly? Generate pdf, execute generation on certain time, or something else? Please elaborate a bit more, since it's kinda complicated to understand (at least for me :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFLib is very heavily documented on the PHP website:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

This may be an option to look into, when creating a report via PDF you can force a line break at a particular spot in order to create these multiple page reports as well.

For example if you had 5 users, you could create a single page report for each user forcing the break in a PDF at the end of each users data. :)

Hope this helps, and that i understood your question correctly!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not terribly particular about how your reports look, you could do them in HTML, and put in CSS rules for printing only that put the page breaks in.

```
.report_header { page-break-before:always; }
```

Then you could just print directly from the page.